# Gray semi transparent div covering links in dropdown menu

Tags: wordpress, mobile, nav

Whenever the website is loaded in mobile everything initially loads fine. However, once the user clicks the nav menu and it drops down, all inks are about 80% covered by a semi transparent dark gray div. The links are still clickable, but it definitely makes for a crappy mobile user experience.

I'm currently using the theme "Responsive" in Wordpress. THe problem may be caused by some CSS I added/edited a few months back to align nav items center of their container. Granted, I ran through "inspect element", disabled everything I could and still couldn't get the div to go away.

Since I'm still not sure where exactly this problem stems from, here's code related to the classes/main suspects "menu" and "main-nav":

```
.js .main-nav {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #585858;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#585858), to(#3d3d3d));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #585858, #3d3d3d);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #585858, #3d3d3d);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #585858, #3d3d3d);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #585858, #3d3d3d);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #585858, #3d3d3d);

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#585858, endColorstr=#3d3d3d);
}

.js .main-nav .menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

.js .main-nav .menu ul {
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.js .main-nav .menu li {
    float: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.js .main-nav .menu li a {
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    color: #444;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.js .main-nav .menu li.current_page_item,
.js .menu .current_page_item a,
.js .menu .current-menu-item a {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.js .main-nav .menu li li:hover {
    background: none !important;
}

.js .main-nav .menu li li a {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 10px 0 30px;
}

.js .main-nav .menu li li li a {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 10px 0 40px;
}

.js .main-nav .menu li a:hover,
.js .main-nav .menu li li a:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
    background-image: none;

    filter: none;
}

.js .main-nav .menu li li a::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    content: "\2013";
}

.js .main-nav .menu li li li a::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    content: "\2013";
}

.js .main-nav .menu li li li a::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 30px;
    content: "\2013";
}

.js .main-nav .menu li ul {
    visibility: visible;
    position: static;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.js .main-nav .menu ul {
    min-width: 0;
}

.js .main-nav #responsive_current_menu_item {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 40px 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.js .main-nav a#responsive_menu_button {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 23px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    background: url("../images/select-icons.png") 0 5px no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.js .main-nav a#responsive_menu_button.responsive-toggle-open {
    background: url("../images/select-icons.png") 0 -46px no-repeat;
}
```

Screenshot:  http://i58.tinypic.com/23vlxmv.png

URL: http://www.medallionenergy.com

Please let me know if any additional info will be needed. Thanks!

Comment: Any more info I can provide?